# How to center slider in css?

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, center

I installed this plugin on a theme. This theme had a slider, but I didn't like it. So I installed this one.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/content-slide/

I tried using this

```
#wpcontent_slider_container{
position:relative;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And this

```
#wpcontent_slider_container{
position:relative;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

And nothing happens.

Do I have to put something in div?

Comment: do you want to center this #wpcontent_slider_container or the content in #wpcontent_slider_container

Comment: This is how I want to look like http://www.dodaj.rs/f/2x/Ay/39nHZAWw/slider-center.jpg

Comment: try recreating the problem with jsfiddle, so we can edit the fiddle and fix it. The css should be width:x, margin:10px auto; and the parent should also have a width and maybe float:left;

Answer (score 2):

Change width

```
#wpcontent_slider_container{
    width: 500px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: try #wpcontent_slider_container{position:absolute; margin-left:Xpx; margin-top:Xpx; } ...

Comment: Same again. Also I don't have any other absolute position in css.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved it:

```
#wpcontent_slider_container {
margin-left: auto !important;
margin-right: auto !important;
}

#wpcontent_slider {
/* Your styling here */
}
```

Without the "!important" thingy the CSS didn't work fo me either.

Answer (score 1):

In `#wpcontent_slider_container's` parent element add

```
text-align:center;
```

to center align your `#wpcontent_slider_container`

Comment: I tried all sugestions and nothing happens. What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you know the width of the slider, here is a little fix that worked for me when center align was being stubborn.

```
#sliderDiv{
   position:relative;
   left:50%;
   margin-left:-(half the width of the div);
  (ex. if div is at 500px it would be margin-left:-250px;)
 }
```

It's not pretty, but it works. You might have to hide the horizontal overflow of the outer container though.

Answer (score 0):

```
#wpcontent_slider_container{
text-align: center;
}
```

or use `<center`> Tag

Comment: I tried all sugestions and nothing happens. What I did wrong?

Comment: is this live project ? past link here

Answer (score 0):

Finally I can fix the problem with the slider ubication in my web page.

Just modify the `style.css` , `.main_img { float:left; margin:15px 10px 0 60px}`, change the values.

Answer (score 0):

Using the 'margin-right' and 'margin-left' on auto !important worked for me as well. It actually also worked even without using the !important command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. These two were the key things, especially the block display mode made the slider centerable by margin.

```
margin 0 auto;
display: block;
```