# How to Center Slider in Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Im using wordpress 5.1 and have the [BuildPress](https://themeforest.net/item/builderpress-wordpress-theme-for-construction-architecture-and-interior-design-industry/20008330) theme. It using WPBakery.

Originally the slider starts from left to right, but somehow i just cant center the slider.   It also didnt work using WPBakery or wordpress theme customization.

I do however successed to center it in Responsive mode.
But again, cant center it at normal mode.

I tried the regular way:

```
.wpb_wrapper {margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;}
```

I have tried to use `position:absolute` or `position:inherit` and such. But without success.

I did read the following thread:

[Cannot figure out how to center div in Wordpress theme](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/293002/cannot-figure-out-how-to-center-div-in-wordpress-theme)

and that as well:

[How to center slider in css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913992/how-to-center-slider-in-css)

And tried the answer, but without success.

Am i missing something?

Site: **http://richdesign.co.il**

Answer (score 0):

In the slider's main div the value of left is set to -366.5px that's maybe by theme so to align the slider at center just add one custom class in that div and overwrite the value of left by 0 (e.g: .custom-class{left: 0!important}). Please check there might be any settings in the theme to make the slider align center.
[please see attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsA1K.png)

Comment: somehow its still on the left

Comment: I have added another solution to this thread please just check that. I hope it will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem while creating the column in VC. I found one extra VC column class (vc_col-lg-3/5) with vc_col-sm-2 in slider div wrapper. So you can remove this class from the page builder. Please see the attached screenshot
[Screenshot One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHgRe.png)
[Screenshot Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAQdf.png)

I hope it will solve this issue.